# Is it possible to use ipywidgets in IDE like Pycharm

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm, ipywidgets

I want to visualize some plots interactively. Now there are python based visualization tools that work with Jupyter notebook or .ipynb files.
When I run the same in pycharm IDE it simply doesn't do anything:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from ipywidgets import interact, fixed
# from IPython.core.display import display

def display_center_effect(x, y, tx, point_list, xlim, ylim):
    tx.SetCenter((x, y))
    transformed_point_list = [tx.TransformPoint(p) for p in point_list]

    plt.scatter(
        list(np.array(transformed_point_list).T)[0],
        list(np.array(transformed_point_list).T)[1],
        marker="^",
        color="red",
        label="transformed points",
    )
    plt.scatter(
        list(np.array(point_list).T)[0],
        list(np.array(point_list).T)[1],
        marker="o",
        color="blue",
        label="original points",
    )
    plt.xlim(xlim)
    plt.ylim(ylim)
    plt.legend(loc=(0.25, 1.01))
# plt.show()

# 2D square centered on (0,0)
points = [
    np.array((-1.0, -1.0)),
    np.array((-1.0, 1.0)),
    np.array((1.0, 1.0)),
    np.array((1.0, -1.0)),
]

# Scale by 2
similarity = sitk.Similarity2DTransform()
similarity.SetScale(2)

interact(
    display_center_effect,
    x=(-10, 10),
    y=(-10, 10),
    tx=fixed(similarity),
    point_list=fixed(points),
    xlim=fixed((-10, 10)),
    ylim=fixed((-10, 10)),
)
```

This MWE runs but doesn't show any plot/graph. Generates the following:

```
interactive(children=(IntSlider(value=0, description='x', max=10, min=-10), IntSlider(value=0, description='y', max=10, min=-10), Output()), _dom_classes=('widget-interact',))
```

I have tried to implement `TKinter` `IPython.core.display` etc. but nothing seems to work.

Comment: @Wayne: that documentation is, unfortunately, incorrect at this point in time. What the asker describes is a long-standing bug of JetBrains' products (primary issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DS-2751/Matplotlib-plots-do-not-work-in-combination-with-widgets-in-Jupyter-notebooks) ).

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately [a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DS-2751/Matplotlib-plots-do-not-work-in-combination-with-widgets-in-Jupyter-notebooks) in JetBrains' products. A possible workaround is to use a [backend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/backends.html) that is not "inline", i.e. opens a new window for the plot. Depending on your operating system, one of them might be able to render the plot, while allowing you to manipulate the widgets from within PyCharm.